# Sorting datatables using a particular field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm using datatables as show here http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables
The default field for sorting is id and that is fine.

However, I also need to be able to redirect to this page from another page so that table must be sorted by another field. I find out what GET query is sent to a server, by it's very long, therefore, there must be another standard way.

So, how do I redirect to a page where this table located to that it causes it sort itself using a particular field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a solution on this post:

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Basically, it's exactly what you're trying to achieve, which is finding out what's coming on the query string.

Comment: are you implying I have to use that super-long string? I know I can use and achieve my goal, but is there any simpler way?